# PyTables Column to normal python list

Tags: python, pytables

I am playing around with PyTables, and stumbled into something I thought would be obvious. I am following the tutorial, but I guess I misunderstand.

I have a PyTables Column object and I want to transfer it's contents to list or numpy array.

So I was hoping there would be something like:

`mylist = h5file.root.mygroup.mytable.cols.mycolumn.to_array()`

I suppose I could iterate, and put each value separately in the list, but I am wondering if I could somehow extract it directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mylist = h5file.root.mygroup.mytable.cols.mycolumn[:]
```